# How do I permanently turn the volume up on a wav file to use it on my phone?

Tags: audio

I want to use some wav files as my ringtone/text tone but a lot of them have a very low volume. I know my phone can be louder because I have put other files in it that are. Is there any way to make the volume higher on a file and save it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) is an excellent free, cross-platform GUI tool for this. Look for "Amplify" in the "Effects" menu.

Comment: Doesn't let me amplify past like 0.1

Comment: Audacity is not the most intuitive, but it should do the trick.  Review the guide

Comment: This did it but it just doesn't sound as high volume as other sound files I have on my phone. Even if I amplify it by a lot it starts to sound weird.

Comment: Well, it's not magic. If your sound file is too quiet, then there may simply be too little information left. You could compare it to an underexposed photograph that you try to restore by turning up the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

SoX's `vol` predicate can increase the volume on the output file.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Goldwave](https://www.goldwave.com/), [free-audio-editor](https://free-audio-editor.com/), [iDealshare VideoGo 7](https://www.idealshare.net) should be able to do the things that you're looking for.

1. [Goldwave](https://www.goldwave.com/)

   After opening your audio file with Goldwave, select **Effect -> Volume -> Maximize Volume** to increase the file's volume. After confirming, you have to save as output file.
2. [free-audio-editor](https://free-audio-editor.com/)

   [image: free-audio-editor]

   After OK, you have to save as output file.
3. [iDealshare VideoGo 7](https://www.idealshare.net)

   [image: iDealshare VideoGo 7]

   1)Import your audio file

   2)Select output format as WAV file

   3)Select **Setting**

   4)Select **Advanced Settings**, then select the increasing **percentage** in the **Volume** field.

   5)Start converting.

Comment: Much better! :)